# import data from table named "document" in odbc database with powerbi

Tags: sql, powerbi, odbc, powerbi-desktop

I'm connected to a database that contains a table named "document", this term is also an sql term at the same time so when I query it, it doesn't recognize it.

I'm used to just add some quotation marks to query it in dbeaver and it works well.

```
select * from "document"`
```

But when I want to write my query in PowerBi to import this table, it doesn't work with the quotation marks.

I also tried it in this format:
`select * from public.document`
Or I tried to don't write any sql query and just select it when I connect to the odbc database, but at the moment of update, the process starts and doesn't stop.

Answer (score 0):

If the table really has double quotes in its name, one of these should work:

Using backtick

```
select * from `"document"`
```

Using double quote as escape:

```
 select * from ""document""
```

Comment: Hi, thank you but it doesn't work.

Comment: The tables is not named "document", it is named document. But because of the fact that this term is still used in sql, as a fonction maybe or for other thing, so I cannot use it vierge to call it.

Comment: You are right. I found [this](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Column-names-with-reserved-keywords-not-being-identified/td-p/836704) for sql server connection. Maybe it helps for ODBC too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I tried the solutions that has been tested on the article that you shared me : 

1) Using square brackets

2) In double quotes

3) In single quotes

4) Casting them as nvarchar()

5) Using table.column_name convention

6) Add space at the end of the column name


But none of this solutions worked for me.